# Accessing PassKit passes created by different app

Tags: ios, passkit

Trying to figure out if it's possible to share my pass with another app produced by an independent developer team.

As [per passkit documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/walletpasses/pass) you have to specify team identifier for the pass which (I'm assuming) limits the scope of accessing pass when using method such as `-[PKPassLibrary passesOfType:]`

Additionally I found following excerpt in the documentation for `[PKPassLibrary passes]`:

> Your app only has access to certain passes according to its entitlements. PassKit doesn’t return passes that your app can’t access.

What if I want another app to be able to access my pass programatically - is my assumption correct meaning it's not possible to share pass between two apps?
Thanks

Comment: It is not possible to share passes between two apps.

Comment: Yes, since I posted the question folks working on the wallet suggested the same and recommended to file an improvement request